# iOS Application Freezes at certain scenarios

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm stuck by an issue where the view of a controller is added dynamically in AppDelegate window.

But oftentimes the view stops responding to events, though the click events are getting logged by the system.

This below portion of code is getting called from a controller:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:STORYBOARD_IDENTIFIER bundle:nil];
    QRcodePopUpView *quickDraw = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"QRcodePopUpView"];
    quickDraw.isTappedOnCards = true;
    quickDraw.delegate = self;
    quickDraw.opLocation = ENLARGE;
    [[ScannerAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].window addSubview: quickDraw.view];
});
```

Comment: You will need to post your code, it's not possible for anyone to guess what might be the issue. Include any error messages or warnings that might be relevant

Comment: Any chance you could post enough code for me to duplicate? As is, it's hard to say what the issue is. While I'm not asking for a full code dump, the code in `AppDelegate` and the `UIViewController` - and yes, `UIView` if it's created outside of the controller - would help. Sometimes when you strip down the code it could help you to see the issue.

Comment: Might be some computational task running on the main thread, but can't say for sure unless I can see the code